# FragmentManager in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmentmanager

I have an activity with a viewpager that contains 2 tabs. Each tab is a host fragment that has 2 child fragments. First fragments are recyclerviews that open up other fragments with FragmentTransactions. I am having trouble creating different backstacks for them.

So in my recyclerview adapter in onBindViewHolder i have the onclicklistener like this:

```
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirstFragment fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
                SecondFragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

                transaction
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2,"Tag")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

If i make the transaction like this from the recyclerview, the backstack is the same for both tabs, so if i open second fragments on tab1, then on tab2, if i go back to tab1 and press back, the second fragment on tab2 gets popped insead.

If i make a button in the FirstFragment outside of the recyclerview and make the fragment transaction from FirstFragment like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, SecondFragment.newInstance(), "Tag");
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

then it works as intended, but i want to do it from the recyclerview.

Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score -1):

You should carry your item click listener logic into the host fragment of the tab. Then in both of your host fragments you should make required transaction by using child fragment manager. Thus, the transactions are kept in the back stack of the host fragments. Then you have to manage these different stacks which are activity's fragment stack, host1's fragment stack and host2's fragment stack. For that purpose, you have to override onBackPressed in your activity then you ask the current visible host fragment for if there is a transaction. If there is you should pop that transaction and return in onBackPressed callback.If there is no let the activity to handle event by calling super.

Comment: I already make the transactions with child fragment managers and overrided onBackPressed in main activity. But how do i carry the click listener to the host fragment? How do i get the image id from the recyclerview into the host fragment?

Comment: You can create a interface for click listener then you should set the listener onViewCreated callback in your fragment.

Comment: I did that but now i don't know how to get the views from the adapter to work with them (i.e for shared elements). For example in my adapter view in on click listener i had `transaction.addSharedElement(holder.Image,"transition");` How can i get the image from the adapter to the fragment? My onClick for the fragment is `public void onImageClick(int position) {}` overrided from the interface

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. I had to pass the ItemView from the ViewHolder in the Adapter along with position. Thank you very much for your help!